# How to show full text of handsontable cells when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

I am using handsontable to display a lot of data and it is a requirement that every row be only one line by default, and that every column has a fixed width. I have done this with the following css:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This works fine:

[image: An example of the css restricting the text to one line]

The issue is that this prevents the user from reading all of the data if it has overflowed. The solution I tried was to use:

```
.highlight {
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: initial;
}
```

This allows the selected cell to overflow and show its full content, however, it seems to break the select box around the cell(s) as shown in the following image:

[image: Broken select box]

Notice how the darker blue select box does not expand to surround the entire cell. I have tried re-rendering the table and that does not change the select box. The effect is exaggerated as more cells with overflows are selected at once (notice how the thinner blue select box is also not properly aligned):

[image: Multiple cells also exaggerates the select box issue]

How can I show the full text of selected cells without breaking the select box?

Comment: Does using the options `autoWrapRow: true` and `stretchH: "all"` not work in your case?